# Clone garage door opener

Tags: arduino, rf, 433mhz

I have a garage door opener that I got when I moved into my condo. However, I only have one, and we have three vehicles in total (1 car + 2 mopeds). I want to permanently have a garage door opener mounted on the mopeds, and I want to clone one of the opener remotes.

I have tried sniffing the 433,92 MHz radio frequency and I found the signal. I've tried decoding it in Audacity and replaying the signal with a FS1000A RF transmitter. Nothing works. I've recently tried decoding the data using RC-Switch but that didn't work either.

I took some photos of the remote just in case someone recognizes it. It does not use rolling codes so I have a hope that it would be "simple" to clone it using my own RX/TX and Arduino.

Any experienced RF people here that can help me?

The remote container box says:

- Tormatic
- MAHS433-01-06
- 433,92MHz AM
- 0130
- 297052587 QC012
- Dickert AHS433

The chip says:

- MAHS433-61
- 433,92MHz AM
- 03008700 QCD50
- V10151208 5029

[image: X]

[image: Y]

[image: Z]

Comment: Most garage door controllers let you have more than one remote and associate different remotes if you'd get out your manual

Comment: Audacity only records at 24kHz, you'd need an SDR to do any cloning. Garage door openers use a rolling code, what makes you think that you can just replay the signal? Anyone would be able to break into your house.

Comment: splice into the manual button located inside the garage, then you can switch in myriad ways

Answer (score 2):

> Any experienced RF people here that can help me?

That might be me....

Save yourself a lot of time and trouble and buy new fobs that can activate a remote relay like this: -

[image]

Then wire the relay contact to operate the internal garage door open/close switch. Your existing system will still work of course but this won't be a problem.

Comment: But this requires me to modify the garade door opener unit? I want to avoid that, just in case it stops working for others. But I totally understand what you mean when you say I would save me alot of time....

Comment: There is usually a contact closure input to the garage door opener available so no modification is required.  It may just be putting it in parallel with the existing receiver.  I have successfully done both approaches over the years.

Comment: Then hack your current fob (keep it in your condo) and use the relay to short the button out. How many people might use the garage? If it's other families too then consider this idea a business opportunity to sell them something that they also might want.

Comment: The dollars could be rolling in LOL.

Comment: Haha, @Andyaka :) I think Kevin White had a point, I will check if the opener has a input available and I can attach to it. Otherwise I'll maybe create my own 433,92 MHz devices that will communicate with a modified remote with a 433 RX that pulls the power low when my custom remote is transmitting.

Comment: Hmmm can anyone explain the phantom downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the sophistication of the remote control, it can involve rotating control codes to prevent replay attacks.

While I, like many, enjoy a good engineering challenge, I am sure the time investment will be significant compared to the $7 off the shelf solution found [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DICKERT-MAHS433-01-and-MAHS433-04-Universal-remote-control-transmitter-/330708721402).